# Why is the 'send_keys' command pressing the enter key after it fills the text box?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fill a form with selenium, which requires me to pull names from a .txt file and assign them to a variable, and then filling a text box using the value from that variable. It successfully fills the desired box, but it presses the 'enter' key right after it fills, which submits the form before the script can fill the other boxes.

I have tried making the script fill the First Name box last, but the form requires information to be filled in the order they are arranged of the website.

```
# Assigns a random name to var 'firstname'
firstname = (random.choice(list(open('names.txt'))))

# Fills the First Name input
first = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#first_name')
first.send_keys(firstname)
```

The code should fill in the first name box and continue to fill in the rest of the form, but instead only fills the first box and then presses the enter key, which prematurely submits the form. I know it is an issue with sending the variable because when I change the code to: first.send_keys('firstname')
The script works as intended.

Comment: I'm guessing that `firstname` has a trailing newline. Try sending `firstname.strip()` instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks! @Loocid